# How to call a method of a different activity from MainActivity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, methods, spreadsheet

I'm making an Android App with Google Spreadsheets. I'm scanning a barcode from a book, looking the info with the Google Books API and then I need to save this info into a sheet.

The following code is inside MainActivity:

```
private class GetBookInfo extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // make Call to the url
        makeCall("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?" +
                    "q=isbn:" + ean_content + "&AIzaSyCpYez5556X4UzPV6rF4kkspj9DsCs_Q_c");

        //print the call in the console
        System.out.println("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?" +
                    "q=isbn:" + ean_content + "&AIzaSyCpYez5556X4UzPV6rF4kkspj9DsCs_Q_c");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // we can start a progress bar here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        String ruta = save_cover(getApplicationContext(), title, book_cover);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Spreadsheets.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

After this code I have `public void makeCall(String stringURL)`. It searchs the book's title, author, date, description and category of the book.

I have another Activity:

```
public class Spreadsheets extends Activity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks
```

In this activity, I have the following code to write into a Google Sheet:

```
 public void setDataToApi (String title, String author, String date, String category, String description) throws IOException {

    String spreadsheetId = "1Gg121IjABekfSTKXg_TQzJgg4boxvYIQnmf_K4YDboo";
    String range = "Sheet1!A2:E2";

    List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
    data1.add(title);
    data1.add(author);
    data1.add(date);
    data1.add(category);
    data1.add(description);

    values.add(data1);
    ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
    valueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
    valueRange.setRange(range);
    valueRange.setValues(values);

    UpdateValuesResponse response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange)
                            .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                            .execute();

    System.out.printf("%d cells updated.", response.getUpdatedCells());

}
```

My problem is that I'm trying to call the setDataToApi method from the onPostExecute method, before the intent, but it does not work at all. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the method of another Activity from outside that Activity. Before the `Intent` is actually dispatched, the other Activity is not yet running. You either need to

1. Move `GetBookInfo` to the `SpreadSheets` Activity so that it can perform the `onPostExecute` directly in the Activity. This requires passing the book's ID via an extra on the `Intent`. Or...
2. Keep `GetBookInfo` where it is in `MainActivity` and pass all the looked up details of the book through extras on the `Intent`.

Comment: Hi @Elan, thank you so much for your help. I'm trying the following code, but it doesn't work.

 `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            String ruta = save_cover(getApplicationContext(), book_title, book_cover);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Spreadsheets.class);
            intent.putExtra(title,book_title);
            intent.putExtra(author,authors);
            intent.putExtra(date,published_date);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }`

Comment: You have a couple of issues there. The first is that the first argument to `putExtra` needs to be a `String`. Secondly, you're calling `finish()` before you call `startActivity()` which exits the current Acitivty before starting the next. If you've exited the current Activity, you can't continue calling code from it.

Comment: It still doesn't work :( 
The first argument is a String, and then I tried to call finish() after startActivity(). I don't know what else can i do

Comment: Hi @Elan, I don't know if you read my last message, but I still have the same problem. Wish you can help me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method being called from 2 different activities, I would recommend putting that method in a separate class. So move `setDataToApi` into it's own Java class, instantiate an object of your new class and use that method in both of your activities that call it.

Or, as Elan said in their answer, use intents and pass information to your other activity using `putExtra` and write your own logic in the `onCreate` method to call `setDataToApi`. Hope this helps!

Comment: If I move `setDataToApi` to another Java class, I have the problem that it cannot be static because I have 
`this.mService.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange) .setValueInputOption("RAW") .execute();`, and it says that this cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Why would you have to make it static? Could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: I don't know for sure, because I'm a beginner in Java/Android, but I've been reading that in order to use a method from another class, it needs to be static.

Comment: That's if you don't want to instantiate an object. If you instantiate the object like so: `MyObj obj = new MyObj();` and then `obj.setDataToApi()` that will work and it doesn't need to be static

Comment: I'm doing that, like 
`Write_Spreadsheets write = new Write_Spreadsheets();
        write.setDataToApi();`, and it doesn't work. It says "Cannot resolve symbol setDatToApi"

Comment: Can you make an edit to your question and put an example of where you call setDataToApi. As of right now there are no uses of it

Comment: I want to call it before the intent on the 'onPostExecute' method 
`@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
String ruta = save_cover(getApplicationContext(), title, book_cover); Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Spreadsheets.class); 
startActivity(intent); } `